# javascript running but jquery not running on eclipse 8.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, eclipse

i have tried everything but simple jquery functions like are not running on my jsp page

code : 
`<input type="button" id="expand3" value="Hide"/>    <div id="result3">hide this</div>`

jquery code :

`$("#expand3").click(function(){
      $("#result3").hide();
     });`

**the jquery code is on the main page and the test to hide is on the page called from the main page**

one more thing ... the below is the code at main page

`   if(probTitleKBaseId!= "")
            kbaseId=document.getElementById("appProbTitle").value;

```
        var contextPath ="/"+(window.location+" ").split("/")[3];

        document.getElementById("KBInfo").innerHTML="";

        document.getElementById("message").style.display="";                        

        makeHttpRequest(contextPath+"/jsp/knowledgeBase/kbResults.jsp?app="+app+"&env="+env+"&ptitle="+ptitle+"&kbaseId="+kbaseId,getResponse,false);
```

`

**i haven't called the `kbresults.jsp` page via AJAX and the button is placed on this page , could this be the reason**

Comment: do you have jquery loaded in your page before your script?

Comment: can u go through browser's console and look for any error there, let us know what u see there.

Comment: @jai yes jquery is loaded before

Comment: @amolsingh then you can wrap your code in `doc ready` block.

Comment: `doc ready` didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should import the jquery libary.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In your browser's console. Like firebug.

Comment: dont have firefox any other way